# Como ajustar essa query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso ajustar essa query para fazer a pesquisa (like) em outra coluna e em outra tabela.

Veja:

```
$query2 = "select distinct(lances.codigo), datacompra, horacompra, cupom from lances, ".$tabelaCad." where lances.idcliente = ".$tabelaCad.".id and lances.datapgto = '0000-00-00' and lances.horapgto = '00:00:00' and (".$tabelaCad.".nome like '%".$cliente."%' or ".$tabelaCad.".usuario like '%".$cliente."%') group by lances.codigo order by lances.datacompra desc, lances.horacompra desc";
```

Atualmente ele faz a busca somente em: `".$tabelaCad.".nome e ".$tabelaCad.".usuario.`

A variável `$tabelaCad` é o nome de uma tabela chamada `cadastro`, e a variável `cliente` é a que recebe o POST da busca.

Eu preciso que ela busque também na coluna `codigo` da tabela `lances` e em uma nova tabela chamada `registro` nas colunas `reg1` e `reg2`.

Como ficaria a query nesse caso? Já tentei diversas formas e não funciona.

Comment: Se as buscas nestas outras tabelas não tiverem nenhuma relação entre si você pode utilizar UNION, agora se estas buscas estiverem correlacionadas então você pode utilizar JOIN.

Comment: Não consegui fazer, pode me ajudar com algum exemplo?

Comment: Fica difícil montar o select incluindo essa tabela `registro` se não sabemos quais campos ela tem em comum com o seu select, não tem como fazer relacionamento. Teria como incluir na sua pergunta as colunas das suas tabelas para que possamos ter um exemplo?

Comment: No caso a tabela `registro` precisaria ter uma coluna com o mesmo nome das outras? Por exemplo o valor de `reg1` é o mesmo valor de `lances.codigo`...